# Abstracting DbContext implementations in C#

Tags: c#, dbcontext

I have three classes that all derive from `DbContext` that is auto generated by Visual Studio that talks to different schema versions of the same database.
 I would like to abstract this into a common class that instantiates the right `DbContext` instance for me based on a version argument passed in as an argument for the constructor and whereby the properties are delegated from the common class to the correct `DbContext` derived class based on the argument to the constructor.

How do I go about doing this in C#?

Comment: It sounds like a Factory pattern to me.

Comment: Yep it is a factory pattern => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ee817667(v=pandp.10)

Comment: Please don't add code in comments - you can edit your question.